# Show a different gallery depending on which button is clicked

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a gallery here with nation select buttons which opens one background image in a div ".displayarea", picking the pics from an array "arrayindex".
And "next"/"previous" select buttons, which open up a separate gallery, in another div ".containsNext", which is placed above the displayarea div.
The close button closes both these divs.
This is working good so far.
Now i want to display a different gallery from different arrays(or can be the same, I don't know what is more efficient)within the .containsNext div, based on which nation button is clicked. Say, for button "croatia", the pic from the photos array on line 3 are displayed, but for the button spain, another array, arraySpain(line 9) would be displayed.
I know we are supposed to post code of what we have tried, but I did not come up with anything useful.
For just the background pic in the displayarea, i have done the following

```
function addImageInto(arrayIndex, container) {
var displayArea = document.querySelector('.displayArea');
if (displayArea.querySelector('.' + container.id)) {
    return;
}
displayArea.innerHTML = '';
```

But I cam not able to achieve my goal with that.
All else is working, the forward() and backwards() functions, the forward function is nested within the rather large function from line 39 to 65.
I could do this by writing the same code over and over for every button, but that cannot be the most useful way to do this.

Link to pen:
http://codepen.io/damianocel/pen/gPggLB

Please click a nations button before you click the "next" or "previous" buttons.
Thank you for any help

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, first you want a different array for each country and second you don't want to re-write your code for every single button.
So for every country you have:
   button with the name of the country
   background image 
   an array of images for a slideshow
My recommendation is using templates. I have used these http://handlebarsjs.com/ before.
So generally templates allow you to cut the repetitive code by introducing a pattern, which is followed in many elements in your code.
So imagine instead of having different array for country name , another for bg-images and another for the slideshow, you can structure your data like this:
http://codepen.io/teft74/pen/MKEQBp?editors=101 (sorry to give you un external like by the site refused to accept my code)

This structure allowes you to use templates.
So for every country you have:
   button with the name of the country
   background image 
   an array of images for a slideshow
In templates you can write this like:

```
 {{#each country}}  // "each" makes loop for each country, returning a button
    <button> {{name}}</button>  
  {{/country}}
```

this will take each country name from your data and place it in the button and will create buttons for each country.
Then when you click on the button it takes you to a different template which is populated with the data from the corresponding button. For example is the user clicks on the button with name: Spain(which is a cell in your country array) you populate your template with background image and gallery from the same cell.

I'm sorry that I can be more specific, but I would have to re-write your code to make it work with templates. It might seem like a lot of work(the idea that I am offering) but once you do it it is much more scalable. You just make the template once and if you want to add another country you just add the data(name, bg-image, gallery[]) and the template generates the whole HTML, CSS and JavaScript functions for you, without you having to write it all over again single time. Check out handlebars and figure out(with my general directions) how you can apply it to your case. Good luck!

Comment: Yes, you kinda got it. Nation button gets a pic from the first array, here a pic from space. Then, as this is displayed, the next button displays another gallery which is placed exactly over the previous div. This extracts pics from another array, ideally from a nation specific array.
The idea was to learn about OOP, prototypes instead of using any framework. The best i can think of is giving a clicked button an active class(like, activeSpain), then get the bg pics from a nation specific array. Something like if(btn.hasClass){forward(argument for specific array}.

Comment: I actually think add a "selected" class on nation button click and removing class from the non selected button and then invoke the forward/backwards functions selecting from just one large array by index position comes closest to the idea.
Everything else requires complete rewritng(lol) or a function for each button.
Which wouldn't be too bad, would it make sense to have one prototype for the very first button and then just change the code in every "new" instance?